# rails, deleting record if exists with a same column value before creating a new record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-activerecord

i have an object person which has a "has_many" relationship with photo object

```
has_many :photos, :foreign_key => 'person_id', :dependent => :destroy
```

and on photo:

```
belongs_to :person, :foreign_key => 'person_id'
```

what i want to do. is during an update of person, if a user uploaded a new photo to that person with the same "kind" (which is an attribute of photo) so the old kind be deleted from the db

for example: 
an update is being performed on person with an uploaded photo with kind "face" 
if a record of photo already exists with the same 'person_id' and the same "kind"
it will first be deleted (not updated) and only the then the new record be saved

thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

your logic is complicated enough to not be built into a framework, you can do what you need in either controller or model, just find the photo you want to replace, destroy it if it exists and create new one

```
photo = person.photos.where(kind: "face").first
photo.destroy if photo

# procede with creating new photo object
```

Comment: i think its actually where(:kind => "face")  :) but this works. i have put in controller in the update action

Comment: yeah it's ruby 1.9 vs 1.8 syntax :)

Comment: oh... I am still on 1.8 :(